LsCache hits on Firefox but Not hitting on Chrome for Laravel Application
I have plesk+litespeed+lscache for laravel. My cache hits on Firefox but not on google chrome. What could be the reason? Here is my config files:
the route group is like below
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'members', 'middleware' => ['auth','license','lscache:private;esi=on;max-age=120']], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['middleware' => ['manage-members|view-member'], 'uses' => 'MembersController@index']);
});

Env is like below
LSCACHE_DEFAULT_TTL=0
LSCACHE_DEFAULT_CACHEABILITY=private;

and finally the .htaccess is like below
<IfModule Litespeed>
CacheLookup on
CacheEngine on esi crawler
   RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Vary:Authorization]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
 
   RewriteEngine On

</IfModule>

